# How do we Displaying a Group Properties along with it's entities?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of Students in a Standard.

```
public class Standard
{
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }        
}
```

In Student class don't have 
a member like **StandardId**  .
So How do we display **StandardId** with each Student entity if we take Students List separately from the Standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var standard = GetStandard();
var studWStId = standard.Students
                        .Select(x=> new {
                                           Student = x, 
                                           StandardId = standard.StandardId 
                                })
                        .ToList();
foraech(stud in studWStId)
{
     System.Console.WriteLine(
         string.Format("Name:{0}, Sid:{1}", stud.Student.Name, stud.StandardId));
}
```

It will create list of anonymous objects with properties `Student` and `StandardId`, which is token from the `standard` holding the students.

Comment: thanks for your help. Am getting anonymous collection ;but i could not see it's items since it is anonymous objects.can you tell me how we can cast it to a list of objects?

Comment: you cannot. because now the structure of Student is different, as it has extra StandardId field. so either you do this, or you change your structure in first place :)

Comment: You can acces anonymous object properties directly in the scope (`{code block}`) where it has been declared (see my updated answer). If you want to return the result of that linq query from some method, you will have to declare a class according to the properties of original anonymous object and use it instead of that anonymous object.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to add new `Property` to `Student` class called `public int StandardId { get; set; }` but if you don't want to do it this way you can do it w LINQ

```
Student student = ...;
List<Standard>() standards = ...;
var standardForStudent = standards.Where(x => x.Students.Any(y => y.Id == student.Id)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: if we add 'StandardId' property in Student ;how do we assign it's value?

Comment: In some place you add student to standard, so you have a student and its standard, right? Then do: `student.StandardId = standard.StandardId;`. If it is not the case I will need more code/information to help you out :)

Comment: In case if we have many Standards and in each Standard many Students are there. I want to group entire Students by it's StandardId. How do we achieve this?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help.